# window.screen.width and window.screen.height not working on iPad 3

Tags: javascript

I'm using the functions

```
window.screen.width
window.screen.height
```

to detect the screen resolution of the user.
They work like a charm on PCs, but they don't on iPad 3.
They output 768 and 1024 instead of 2048 and 1536.

Can somebody help me, please?
Thank you in advance

Comment: That is correct iPad 2 resolution, are you talking about new iPad?

Comment: Yep, sorry I've made a mistake ;)

Comment: And what jquery has to do with that?

Answer (score 8):

Yep. Welcome to the interesting world of Mobile devices!

The iPad 3 (and other retina devices) use `window.devicePixelRatio` set to `2` to show that they have different css pixels to logical pixels. An iPad 3 still reports 1024 × 768, as that is the number of CSS pixels.

As another source of confusion, some Android devices report the viewport width, and some the physical width, meaning that if you ask some Android devices, the `window.screen.height` will be thousands and thousands if the document is long.

In short, for your problem, use `window.devicePixelRatio` as a multiplier. I'd use something like

```
if(!window.devicePixelRatio) {
    window.devicePixelRatio = 1;
}
```

To ensure that if it isn't set that it's declared as 1 before you start.

Comment: Rich thank you for your answer, however your solution doesn't seem to work.
I've tried it and I still get 768 and 1024.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: Yes, you will. If you want the real size, multiply it by devicePixelRatio.

Comment: window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio
window.screen.heigth * window.devicePixelRatio
Right?

Comment: Yes. Though in reality you rarely if ever need to do this conversion…

Comment: window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio returns NaN

Comment: Try again, I dropped one of the !.

Comment: Hi @RichBradshaw I had a problem like the question here now, I'm new to the Mobile device world, where can I find documentation like this in order to have a preview background before continue working?

Answer (score 4):

```
if(window.devicePixelRatio !== undefined) {
    dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
} else {
    dpr = 1;
}

var screen_width = window.screen.width * dpr;
var screen_height = window.screen.height * dpr;
```

This solution works perfectly.

Comment: window.devicePixelRation has been 1 on every device I've tried, be it ipad, iphone or android..

Comment: window.devicePixelRatio returned 2 on iPad/iPhone for me

Comment: The value should be 2 on Retina display devices.