# Use Viewport for Specific Widths

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I have an interesting problem.

At the company I am working with, we are building a website for a client from a photoshop template design and the site needs to be responsive.

The sites design doesn't crunch well between desktop and mobile, the project being late we decided to design the full width site, and a site for mobile phones.

That being said, this is what needs to happen.

Before 600px, everything just functions like a boring non-responsive website on all devices. At and below 600px, the site becomes responsive.

My problem is viewports. If I specify a viewport, it will look bad on the iPad because it shrinks it to the device scale.

My original idea was to use jQuery to detect window size and at 600px and below, it would insert the meta tag.

But this does not work as without the viewport tag (which screws up that site on any devices bigger than 600px) it cannot detect the actual screen size.

Has anyone ran into this problem before?

Comment: It sounds like you might be trying to reinvent the wheel a bit here. A lot of the quirks and problems of dealing with device sizes and resolutions have been worked out. Have you looked into `@media` queries?

Comment: Ya. The whole site is based off of them.

Comment: And normally I wouldn't do this, but the site needs to be deployed and the design is not friendly to tablets.

Comment: I'm sorry - I misread. My mistake.

Comment: So, `jQuery('body').width()` isn't working for you? That should tend to work even without a viewport tag.

Comment: No, it returns the same as `$(window).width();`

Comment: `window.devicePixelRatio` in combo with `width`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548003/window-screen-width-and-window-screen-height-not-working-on-ipad-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was `window.screen.availWidth;` This got the width of the device without the use of viewports.